# DO-254 and microprocessors: how does it apply?

Tags: flight-controls, avionics

How does DO-254 apply to commercial processors? For instance, I've noticed that "DO-254 certifiable" processors exist. Does that mean that these were designed with inherent redundancy?

Comment: I don't see why this would be off-topic, it's about aviation regulations.

Comment: Agree with @Federico.  This is a valid question concerning certification of avionics.

Comment: I don't know enough to provide a full answer, but it isn't the device that is certified to DO-254, it is the design and verification process used to develop the code.  I suspect that this statement is just a marketing tactic.  (i.e.  if you are designing to DO-254 and are faced with a choice between two devices, you might be inclined to select one over the other simply for the peace of mind this phrase induces...)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

DO-254 is for Airborne Electronic Hardware. Redundancy isn't necessarily required for DO-254. I would expect that the processor manufacturer would be able to provide a data package with the necessary documentation if a company were to use it in a DO-254 certifiable product.

In my experience, however, DO-254 is applied for custom micro-coded components only (for the FAA at least). DO-254 was a way to apply concepts similar to DO-178 to things like PLDs, FPGAs, and ASICs to prevent a "firmware" gap in certification.